# In a textbox does the CaretIndex property consider newlines as positions?

Tags: c#, wpf

In c# WPF textbox - does the CaretIndex consider \r\n and other un-displayable characters as 1 position in the index, or 2 or none? Is this different for Getting and Setting?

The MSDN article on the subject doesnt say anything:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretindex(v=vs.110).aspx

I'm working on building a touchscreen keyboard control, and I need to modify the text based on the current insertion point. I'm wondering how things like "enter" affect the CaretIndex - will it move 2 places, or none, etc